# Rename files within folder - Unicode equivalent function

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a function that renames the files within a directory structure. The problem that i am facing is that the following code which i've made does not compile when setting unicode character set in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 express edition.

I know that there are function equivalent for unicode but i am unable to make the code work. Any input on how i could make this work for unicode is most welcomed.

Here is the code :

```
void Subdir(char st[1000]){

char *s;
char sDir[MAX_PATH] = "\0", sTmp[MAX_PATH] = "\0";
int gasit;

WIN32_FIND_DATA theFiles;
HANDLE hTheFiles;

ZeroMemory(&theFiles, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

s = st;
strcat(s, "\\");
strcpy_s(sDir, s);
strcat_s(sDir, "*");
rezultat.resize(0);

hTheFiles = FindFirstFile(sDir, &theFiles);
if (hTheFiles == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;

sDir[strlen(sDir) - 1] = 0;

do {

    if ((!strcmp(".", theFiles.cFileName)) || (!strcmp("..", theFiles.cFileName)))
        continue;

    if (theFiles.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY){
        strcpy_s(sTmp, sDir);
        strcat_s(sTmp, theFiles.cFileName);
        strcat_s(sTmp, "\\");
        FisiereSubdir(sTmp);
    }
    else {


        std::string str(s);
        gasit = str.find_first_of("\\");
        while (gasit != string::npos){
            if (gasit > 0){
                rezultat.push_back(str.substr(0, gasit));
            }
            str = str.substr(gasit + 1);
            gasit = str.find_first_of("\\");
        }
        if (str.length() > 0){
            rezultat.push_back(s);
        }

        k = rezultat.size();
        //(cin.get() << '\n');
        if ((k % 4) == 0)
        {
            f_path = rezultat[k - 2] + string("_") + rezultat[k - 1] + string("_") + theFiles.cFileName;
            const char * nume_nou = f_path.c_str();
            const char * nume_vechi = theFiles.cFileName;

            if (_chdir(s)) 
            {

                switch (errno)
                {
                case ENOENT:
                    printf("No such directory: %s\n");
                    break;
                case EINVAL:
                    printf("Incorect parameter.\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Unknown error.\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                redenumit = rename(nume_vechi, nume_nou);

                if (redenumit == 0)
                    puts("Modification done !");
                else
                    perror("Modification impossible !");
            }
        }
    }
} while (FindNextFile(hTheFiles, &theFiles));

FindClose(hTheFiles);

return;
```

}

Comment: What's the compile error?

Comment: 1) What error are you getting 2) Without looking too deeply, I can say "char" and "std::string" won't work with unicode.  Use wchar_t and std::wstring instead.

Answer (score 0):

In Win32, most API functions are really a conditional define based on whether or not you are using unicode, something like the following (hit F12 when the cursor is on an identifier to see the definition, or right-click->go to definition in visual studio):

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define SomeWin32Function SomeWin32FunctionW
#else
#define SomeWin32Function SomeWin32FunctionA
#endif
```

Basically, the unicode versions of Win32 functions require `wchar_t*` and `wchar_t` characters. ANSI requires `char*` and `char` characters. The difference of course being Unicode is a 16-bit character set and ANSI is an 8-bit character set, and processing is going to be different for different character sets.

With that in mind, I notice that a few things should resolve this:

1. Replace `char *` and `char` with `wchar_t *` and `wchar_t` (or the `WCHAR` typedef).
2. Replace any `std::string` with `std::wstring`
3. Replace any string literal, for instance `"\\"` with the wide character equivalent `L"\\"`
4. Replace your string functions with their wide character equivalents. Win32 functions should automatically call either the ANSI or unicode version based on whether or not you've entered `#define UNICODE`. Functions such as `strcat` will need to be replaced with the appropriate function, such as `wcscat` (wide-character string concatenation). Here is an msdn reference page for at least the the strcat wide character version, other string functions such as `strcmp`, `strcpy`, etc. have similar naming conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x0y282.aspx